# How can i get all src in json?

Tags: python, scrapy

**How can i get all images src in json?**

```
 def parse(self, response):

    products = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())['products']
    for product in products:
        item = ShopifyItem()

        item['title'] = product['title']

        for image in product['images']:
            item['src'] = image['src']
```

json code: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TivQ6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because you are overwriting the `src` to same `item['src']`.
Use a list and append URLs to the list.

Check the sample code:

```
for product in products:
        item = ShopifyItem()

        item['title'] = product['title']
        item['src'] = []

        for image in product['images']:
            item['src'].append(image['src'])
```

Comment: Hi Arun Augustine Thank you